# Recursively enter nested object into tree view component inside return statement of a React functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, treeview

I have a hierarchical object. Looks like this:

```
{
  id: 74,
  parentId: null,
  children: [
    {
      id: 62,
      parentId: 74,
      children: [{ id: 56, parentId: 62 }, { id: 63, parentId: 62 }],
    },
    {
      id: 86,
      parentId: 74,
      children: [
        {
          id: 80,
          parentId: 86,
          children: [{ id: 81, parentId: 80 }, { id: 76, parentId: 80 }],
        },
        { id: 87, parentId: 86 },
      ],
    },
  ],
};
```

I want to display it on my front end using the tree view module I got from the https://mui.com/material-ui/react-tree-view/
The syntax for tree view is like this:

```
 return (
    <TreeView
      aria-label="file system navigator"
      defaultCollapseIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
      defaultExpandIcon={<ChevronRightIcon />}
      sx={{ height: 240, flexGrow: 1, maxWidth: 400, overflowY: 'auto' }}
    >
      <TreeItem nodeId="1" label="Applications">
        <TreeItem nodeId="2" label="Calendar" />
      </TreeItem>
      <TreeItem nodeId="5" label="Documents">
        <TreeItem nodeId="10" label="OSS" />
        <TreeItem nodeId="6" label="MUI">
          <TreeItem nodeId="8" label="index.js" />
        </TreeItem>
      </TreeItem>
    </TreeView>
  );
}
```

How can I loop over my object and enter the respective values into the parents and corresponding children tree items inside this tree syntax? It should look like this:

```
<TreeItem nodeId="74" label="74">
 <TreeItem nodeId="62" label="62">
  <TreeItem nodeId="52" label="52"/>
 <TreeItem />
.
.
.
<TreeItem />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do something like this

```
const renderTree = tree => {
  return <TreeItem key={tree.id} nodeId={tree.id} label={tree.id}>
          {tree.children && tree.children.map(renderTree)}
       </TreeItem>

} 


return (
    <TreeView
      aria-label="file system navigator"
      defaultCollapseIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
      defaultExpandIcon={<ChevronRightIcon />}
      sx={{ height: 240, flexGrow: 1, maxWidth: 400, overflowY: 'auto' }}
    >
      {renderTree(tree)}
    </TreeView>
  );
```

Comment: thank you so much! Now all I need is to write a condition so that only the lowest level children are clickable buttons (In my actual project on clicking the names of the said children, they will be passed as props to another component called inside the functional component where I'm making the tree view)